# How to make a spinning refresh icon in android

Tags: android, rotation, progress-bar, android-animation

I want to make a icon spin when I click on it, as a progress bar does, and then when my app has finished doing what the button is meant to, it stops spinning.

I want to take am image like so: https://www.google.co.za/search?q=refresh+icon&safe=off&espv=2&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=kaomU8mWC4eshQe7soHgAQ&ved=0CCoQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=912

Can I change the image of a progress bar?

I have tried an animation, but I didn't get it to work,

What is my best option?

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 359,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="0.5"
    android:pivotY="0.5"         
   />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it like this and it worked great for me :

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 359, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
iv.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

I think you are missing the `duration`...

Comment: How do I change this to an xml version? as there is no pivotType and PivotValue. only pivot?

Comment: i don't think all the elements can be set in the xml. why do you need that?

Comment: because otherwise it rotates around the top point x:0 y:0 . Se what I have so far in my edit

Comment: did you try adding `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` in your xml?

Comment: Yup. it doesnt help. It rotates around the point x=0;y=0  . I need it to rotate around the middle.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate about the center use 50%

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"         
   />
```